# Static methods in access in jar

Tags: java, static

I have a java class with 3 static(public static) methods and 2 non- static (public)methods.
I have packaged the file in a jar file.
Now when i used this jar file to my another java project in eclipse .. then only the static methods are accesible.
can I have an explanation for this?

Comment: how you are accessing non static methods?

Comment: static methods can be accessed directly.however to access non static methods you require instance of that class

Comment: Please update how you are accessing non-static methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can access not static methods by creating instance.

```
MyClassName myClass = new MyClassName();
myClass.methodName();
```

Or

```
new MyClassName().methodName();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Foo f = new Foo();
f.nonStaticMethod()
```